# i need to fetch mysql data between age

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a MySQL table having `dob(DATE format)` field, now I need to fetch records by age.For example I have written a query to fetch records greater than 18 years. I need to fetch records by age lying in `18 year to 30 year` old.
Can someone tell me exact query for this problem. Already Tried Query is

```
SELECT id,dob FROM profiles WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 18 YEAR) > dob;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use between if you also would incluse 18 or 30 years:

```
SELECT id,dob FROM profiles WHERE dob between DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 18 YEAR) and DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 YEAR)
```

or if thy should excluded:

```
SELECT id,dob FROM profiles WHERE dob < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 18 YEAR) and dob > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 YEAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

I honestly hate substracting dates, since the functions can do odd stuff if you put the data in different order. I prefer adding, easier and error free :P

```
SELECT id,dob FROM profiles WHERE DATE_ADD(dob,INTERVAL 18 YEAR) >= CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(dob,INTERVAL 30 YEAR) <= CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set sdate := DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 18 YEAR);
set edate := DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 YEAR);
SELECT id,dob FROM profiles 
WHERE dob < sdate and dob > edate;
```

This is much better as per performance on large/huge table.